# Using themes in print layout in QGIS

Tags: qgis, printing, layouts, theme

I can't work out how to create a print layout directly from a map theme - even though the QGIS 3.10 manual says "All configured themes are also accessible in the print layout, allowing you to create different map items based on specific themes."

Anyone know how?

Comment: Activate a theme in QGIS main window: it will affect the rendering of the map in print layout (you migjt need to refresh the layout / F5 under win)

Comment: many thanks. It was the 'follow map themes' in print layout that I missed.

Answer (score 1):

You can see below GIF for an "How To" to get started.

[image: QGIS create theme and use in layout]